# Is Canvas3D.fps equal to the entire window's FPS?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, frame-rate, diagnostics

Confusingly the `Window` type in Qt Quick doesn't have a `fps` (frames per second) property, but `Canvas3D` does. So I'm measuring my app's fps by having a dummy `Canvas3D` and displaying *its* `fps` property. Is this a valid approach? I think so, because the `Canvas3D` is probably redrawn exactly at the same moments as the window.

I'd like your answers to provide either proof or a reference for what they claim, so I can be sure I'm getting the right performance measurements.

Comment: I have 0 experience with Qt, but most GUI libraries, unlike games, do not redraw the whole window continuously, but only when something changes (element is mouseovered, clicked, change triggered from code, etc). I suppose that Qt will only continuously redraw the Canvas3D, but not the window. So it wouldn't make sense to measure "frames per second" of something that changes mostly based on user input. Again, I never used Qt, just using my common knowledge.

Comment: @Kroltan: Thanks, your comment reflects the thoughts that came to me after I posted this question.